# Show that $\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{k^2}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, upper-lower-bounds

I want to show that the following inequality holds for all $k\in\mathbb{N},k\geq 1$:

$$
\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\leq\frac{1}{k^2}
$$

I already know that it is bounded. It also know that $1+x\leq e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. and that $e^x\leq\frac{1}{1-x}$ for all $x\in [0,1)$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)=0$ and any sequence with a limit is bounded.

Comment: I edited my question, since I know that the expression is bounded but I want to provide this specific bound.